# ie11 layout issues with display: inline-block percentage

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-11

Positioning a div with display inline-block within another div with display inline-block. Applying percentage left value 20%.

All browsers except ie11 correctly position the div left 20%. ie11 doesn't apply any left value.

When parent is set to position: block, ie11 respects the left percentage value.

Is this a known bug?
Is there a workaround without floating parent div?

```css
.outer{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.parent{
  background: #02a;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.boxes {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.positioned {
  background: #0a0;
}
.boxes.relative{
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
}
.relative{
  position: relative;
}
.boxes.percent{
  background: red;
  left: 20%;
}
.block{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  works correctly:
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='boxes'>One</div>
    <div class='boxes positioned'>Two</div>
    <div class='boxes'>Three</div>
    <div class='boxes'>Four</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='outer'>
percentage value `left: 20%` doesn't work:
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='boxes'>One</div>
    <div class='boxes positioned relative percent'>Two</div>
    <div class='boxes'>Three</div>
    <div class='boxes'>Four</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='outer'>
parent has `display: block`
  <div class='parent block'>
    <div class='boxes'>One</div>
    <div class='boxes positioned relative percent'>Two</div>
    <div class='boxes'>Three</div>
    <div class='boxes'>Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: what if you keep the parent inline-block and you put inside it anothe wrapper that you keep block and then your child element

Comment: not sure of what you expect . relative + coordonate will move the parent of that much at screen ...  **but % seems to mind the width of the parent. Is this what you want ?** transform:translatex(20%); will move the element of 20% of its own size and that works fine with IE. https://jsbin.com/fiyusitaca/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: spec  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#relative says : **`relative
    The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements; thus, the space given for the element in the page layout is the same as if position were static.`** , so transform should .

Comment: Many thanks guys, bu this doesn't explain why ie doesn't apply the left percent value at all. All other browsers do. The element marked 'two' should be moved rightwards by a value other than 0, whilst not affecting its siblings. It is not displaying the expected behavior.

Comment: I try to test the issue with IE 11 and I can see the issue in it. Based on my test result, I found that it can be related to the `padding` that you had set for the `parent` class. I noticed that when I remove it and again apply it from developer tools then it display the box in the proper location as it gets display in other browsers. [See here.](https://imgur.com/a/AV7gfDp) (Click image after opening it.) I try to check for any possible workaround but did not get any working workaround for it. I suggest you can provide feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Minal Chauhan - thank you for the picture --> that is what all browsers other ie11 look like. ie11 fails to move box Two right at all. I was not allowed to add a picture of what it looks like, but it moves down the correct 15px, but right 0, so there is no overlap with box Three.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thank you for your suggestion, though even adding a wrapper div inside 'parent' with `style=width:100%;` doesn't help ie11 to calculate the width of the containing block - `parent.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT --> unfortunately, removing the padding in the source code doesn't help, but when you force ie11 to re-caulculate styles after page load, as you did with dev tools, it then applies the position correctly.
Strange

Comment: I just discovered that if we change the `width: 80px` rule in the style of *`.boxes`* to `min-width: 80px` it works correctly in ie11, without breaking any other browsers. I don't know of any documented bug that works like this

Comment: @SimonScharf, it's good to know that you found the workaround for this issue. I suggest you post your workaround as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in the layout engine.

The workaround is a to use '`min-width`' instead of '`width`' which forces ie11 to honor the positions